# Hibernate - Como buscar todas as linhas de uma tabela com o Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Não estou conseguindo buscar todas as linhas de uma tabela com o Hibernate. Alguém sabe o nome do método que faz isto?

Comment: Olá Gabriel! Você teria algum código para nos mostrar? Sua dúvida não ficou clara, pois há diferentes maneiras de fazer isto: Criteria, JPQL ou consulta nativa. Se estiver usando algum framework (como o Spring), aparecem mais opções.

Answer (score 2):

Supondo uma entidade chamada `Pessoa`, que está corretamente mapeada no seu sistema, e uma variável `session` em que você já iniciou uma sessão do Hibernate, você quer algo assim para recuperar todos os registros:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Pessoa");
List<Pessoa> list = query.list();
```

O Hibernate faz uso da linguagem HQL para consultas (é uma das opções, há outras). Saiba mais a respeito dando uma olhada na [documentação](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/pt-BR/html/queryhql.html).

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer isso:

```
public <T> List<T> listarTodos(Class<T> tipo) {
    return em.createQuery("FROM " + tipo.getSimpleName(), tipo).getResultList();
}
```

Você usaria isso assim:

```
List<Pessoa> todasAsPessoas = listarTodos(Pessoa.class);
List<Empresa> todasAsEmpresas = listarTodos(Empresa.class);
```

Observe que o método é genérico. A lista que ele retorna tem o mesmo tipo do `Class` que você passa como parâmetro.

O `em` aqui é o `EntityManager`. Se você necessitar de algo mais complexo para obter uma instância do `EntityManager`, vai ter que adaptar esse código.

Observe que é usado o [método `createQuery(String, Class<?>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) que devolve um `TypedQuery<T>` e tem dois parâmetros. Isso é preferível do que usar o [método similar `createQuery(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery-java.lang.String-) que retorna uma `Query` sem tipo e só tem um parâmetro, pois nesse caso o `getResultList()` forneceria uma `List` bruta sem o tipo genérico.

Só tome cuidado para não usar isso em uma tabela com milhões de registros e consumir a memória toda construindo a lista de resultados, lembre-se que isso daí vai virar um `SELECT` sem `WHERE` e nem paginação. Algo parecido também acontece se a entidade buscada tiver um monte de relacionamentos que estejam marcados com `@ManyToOne`, `@OneToOne` e/ou `fetchType = FetchType.EAGER` que acabem praticamente provocando o carregamento do banco de dados inteiro na memória.

Answer (score 0):

o código que faz isso se chama hql, resumindo seria um sql do Hibernate, sua sintaxe seria essa:

```
 Query q = em.createQuery("FROM Item_Pedido As a WHERE a.id_pedido = :para1");
```

No caso de uma lista para uma dataTable você faria assim, ja com passagem de parametros.

```
public List<Item_Pedido> listaItemPorPedido(Long id) {
      String aux = String.valueOf(id);
    Query q = em.createQuery("FROM Item_Pedido As a WHERE a.id_pedido = :para1");
    q.setParameter("para1", aux);
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Eu recomendo explicitar o `SELECT` ao invés de começar a consulta apenas com `FROM`:

```
String jpql = "SELECT pessoa FROM Pessoa pessoa";
Query query = em.createQuery(jpql);
List<Pessoa> pessoas = em.getResultList();
```

Também pode fazer isto usando query nativa:

```
String jpql = "SELECT pessoa.id, pessoa.nome FROM Pessoa pessoa";
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(jpql);
List<Object[]> pessoas = em.getResultList();
```

#### Por que não usar apenas o FROM, sem SELECT?

Não recomendo fazer a consulta começando pela claúsula `FROM`, como esta abaixo:

```
String jpql = "FROM Pessoa";
Query query = em.createQuery(jpql);
List<Pessoa> pessoas = em.getResultList();
```

O motivo? Se você resolver fazer um JOIN entre duas tabelas desta maneira, algo bem comum nas versões antigas do Hibernate quando as entidades não eram relacionadas:

```
String jpql = "FROM Pessoa pessoa, FROM Cliente cliente WHERE pessoa.cpf = cliente.cpf";
```

O Hibernate não vai retornar uma Pessoa, mas um array de objetos: `Object[]`. Na primeira posição terá a Pessoa e na segunda terá o Cliente. Isto [pode acontecer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431312/difference-between-join-and-join-fetch-in-hibernate/23377714#comment55574622_28649270) quando você usa `JOIN FETCH`, por isto não recomendo omitir o `SELECT`.

Portanto, desde então, recomendo fazer consultas explicitando o `SELECT`.